# Make proxy on Kotlin class from a Java library using ASM

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-interop

I have a Java library that creates a proxy using ASM.

At one point, user sends a Kotlin class to it. I can detect it is a Kotlin class from Java, but I don't know how can I make a proxy from it? Everything what I read from such class is meaningless.

The scenario is the following

- user sends a Kotlin class
- I make a proxy
- finally, I make an instance of such class

what would be the best way to do so?

#### EDIT

I just realized that one of the reasons why I can't override Kotlin functions is because they are generated as `final` methods in the bytecode. Is there a way to tell Kotlin not to do so?

Comment: Try making the kotlin class and methods open, and check if that help with final methods in bytecode

Comment: True. Using `open` helped.

Comment: It's not totally clear what you're asking here. The bytecode of Kotlin classes should be comparable with that of Java classes, so it should work the same way. What's the specific issue you're having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I had was that generated classes and methods are `final`. The ASM code I am using was not processing final methods as they can not be overwritten.

The solution is to mark classes and functions in Kotlin as `open`. You can do this manually or using `all-open` plugin.

Here is a page that explains the issue: https://blog.frankel.ch/open-your-classes-and-methods-in-kotlin/